# StackOverflowError play framework at compilation

Tags: java, playframework, stack-overflow, typesafe-activator

I have a problem with Play framework, I don't know why... Impossible to compile my project ... When I compile (with "activator run") I have a "stackoverflow" error (see below for the link of the error) and I don't understand ...

I think the error comes from my file "/conf/routes" ... I try to delete everything and do "activator clean" then "activator compile" when the file is empty, everything works ... Adds line by line and I test again and again with activator clean and compile ... And at some point I have the stackoverflow error that happens ...
I don't understand why ... Someone already had this mistake?

I use play framework 2.5.9 with JAVA, Ebean, Postgresql, html simple page, javascript, angularjs, ajax, etc.

The trace of the error log is here : http://pastebin.com/PikH03mn

My conf routes:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

#######################
#       PERSON        #
#######################
# Create on person
POST    /person                     controllers.PersonController.personCreate
# Get All person
GET     /persons                    controllers.PersonController.persons
# Get just one person
GET     /person/:id                 controllers.PersonController.person(id: Long)
# Update one person
PUT     /person/:id                 controllers.PersonController.personUpdate(id: Long)
# Delete one person
DELETE  /person/:id                 controllers.PersonController.personDelete(id: Long)
# Check if the user exist to connect
POST    /login                      controllers.PersonController.login
# Logout the person
POST    /logout                     controllers.PersonController.logout
# Check if the user is already connect or not
GET     /isConnected/:id/:token     controllers.PersonController.isConnected(id: Int, token: String)
# Get all products for a seller
GET     /person/:id/products        controllers.PersonController.getAllProductsForSeller(id: Long)
# Get all seller companies
GET     /persons/seller           controllers.PersonController.getAllSeller()
# PAGE HTML
# Index
GET /                               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="html/index.html")
GET /indexJS                        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="javascripts/index.js")

# Create a person
GET /createPerson                   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="html/createPerson.html")
GET /createPersonJS                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="javascripts/createPerson.js")

# Login a person
GET /login                          controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="html/login.html")
GET /loginJS                        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="javascripts/login.js")

# Home for SU when connect
#GET /SU/home                        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="html/homeSU.html")
#GET /SU/homeSUJS                    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="javascripts/homeSU.js")
etc....
```

Comment: Is that your full routes file? If so, we have far more entires in ours and it compiles just fine. I would probably see if there's a dubious entry in your routes file since -- from what I can see -- it's the typer itself that has issues rather than something that comes from the play framework.

Comment: @rethab thanks for the response :). No, my routes files is approximately 150 lines... I don't understand why it's cause this overflow error...

Comment: So i don't know why I have this error... I replace my route by GET    /js/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/javascripts", file)
GET    /*file                  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/html", file)
GET    /lib/*file              controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/lib", file) to replace all my routes and can be work again...  Thanks :)